# Erlang: Matching strings in guard statement

Tags: string, erlang, string-matching

Started working with erlang quite recently and ran into the problem above, how do you go about comparing two strings in a guard statement? Tried the string:equal(x,y) method but couldn't get it to work inside a guard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the function `string:equal/2` to compare strings; you can use the operators `==` or `=:=`, which are allowed in guard tests.  For example:

```
foo(A, B) when A =:= B ->
    equal;
foo(_, _) ->
    not_equal.
```

Though in most cases you'd want to use pattern matching instead, as described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26125940/113848).

---

NB: As of Erlang/OTP 20.0, `string:equal(A, B)` is no longer equivalent to `A =:= B`.  `string:equal/2` now operates on grapheme clusters, and there are also [`string:equal/3` and `string:equal/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#equal-3) that can optionally ignore case when comparing and do Unicode normalisation.  So you need to understand what you mean by "equal" before settling on a comparison method.

Answer (score 9):

You could use pattern matching like this:

```
are_the_same(A, A) ->
  true;
are_the_same(_, _) ->
  false.
```

In first clause both arguments are named `A` which will result in them being pattern matched against each other. Or to be exact first argument will be bind to `A` variable with use of `=` operator, and than second argument will be bind to `A` variable with `=` operator, but since `A` is bound already it will be treated as "comparision". You can read [more about this in docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77890).

And of course you could write write first clouse with use of guard like:

```
are_the_same(A, B) when A =:= B ->
```

Comment: Using pattern matching is the most efficient way of doing anything in erlang.
This becomes very important when building complex softwares.

Answer (score 4):

The functions you can use in guards are limited because of the nature of Erlang's scheduling; specifically, Erlang aims to avoid side-effects in guard statements (e.g., calling to another process) because guards are evaluated by the scheduler and do not count against reductions. This is why `string:equal` does not work.

That being said, you can use Erlang's pattern matching to match strings. Please bear in mind the use of strings as lists, binaries, or iolists (nested lists/binaries) in Erlang, and make sure you're testing/passing strings of the right type (iolists are particularly hard to pattern match and are usually best handled with the `re` module, or converting them to binaries via `iolist_to_binary`).

For example, say we want a function that tests to see if a string begins with "foo":

```
bar("foo" ++ _Rest) -> true;
bar(<<"foo", Rest/binary>>) -> true;
bar(_Else) -> false.
```

If you just want to test for a particular string, it's even easier:

```
bar("foo") -> true;
bar(<<"foo">>) -> true;
bar(_Else) -> false.
```

Comment: @legoscia answers solved it but if you don't mind: How would you pattern match a variable against another variable using this method? and what exactly does the <<_, _>> expression do?

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the limitations of pattern matching is exactly what you describe: you can't match another variable with a list or binary (e.g., neither `bar(Test ++ _Rest, Test)` nor `bar(<<Test/binary, _Rest/binary>>, Test)` will work). @legoscia's solution is best when matching entire variables. If you're looking for partial matches, you will have to bind the variable you are testing in the function declaration and use a case statement to assert the match.

Comment: And <<_,_>>, unless I'm mistaken, matches a two-byte binary.

Comment: Ah, okay. So matching variables: '=:=' and to do partial matching use what you described above?

Comment: Indeed. And if the partial matching doesn't work as I describe, you can always iterate through the elements of the list or the bytes of the binary (`bar(_Test = [H|TestRest], _Data = [H|DataRest]) -> bar(TestRest, DataRest); (_Test, []) -> true; bar(_Test, _Data) -> false.`)